# How to perform Ctrl +v operation in selenium webdriver using python

Tags: python, selenium

Can any one give sample code for Ctrl +v operation in selenium webdriver using python

Answer (score 0):

We can use ActionsChains utility to achieve this. Example is given below:

```
ActionsChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Lemme know if this helps you.